# the <Router> is rendered only once, how can i get the location.pathname when it's changed?

Tags: react-router

in 0.13.x, i can do this by:

```js
ReactRouter.run(Routers, ReactRouter.HistoryLocation, function (Component, state) {
    React.render(<Component />, document.getElementById("global_container"), function () {
      console.log("render！");
      //i can get state here!
    });
  });
```

but in 1.0.x, how can i get the location.pathname?

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentWillReceiveProps` on your route components, or the `onUpdate` hook on the `<Router>`.